# Combining data from different tables

Tags: mysql

I think I have a little blackout at the moment...

I have several MySQL-tables like this:

bookings:

id - int
starttime - datetime
endtime - datetime
user1 - int
user2 - int

```
+--+--------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|id|    starttime       |      endtime      |user1|user2|
+--+--------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
|1 |2017-03-17 15:00:00 |2017-03-17 16:00:00|  1  |  3  |
+--+--------------------+-------------------+-----+-----+
```

Table users:
id - int
username - varchar

```
+--+--------+
|id|username|
+--+--------+
|1 |Rainer  |
|2 |Horst   |
+-----------+
```

Now I want to make a query, getting the starttime, the endtime and the names of my users in one row.

Can anybody help, please?

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Gardinero

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make one join for each column. Try this:

```
SELECT b.*, u1.username username1, u2.username username2
FROM bookings b
LEFT JOIN users u1 ON b.user1 = u1.id
LEFT JOIN users u2 ON b.user2 = u2.id
```

Comment: Perfect, that is the solution for my case.
Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
SELECT b.*, u.username
FROM bookings b
LEFT JOIN users u
ON b.user1 = u.id
  OR b.user2 = u.id
```

Create a join from one table to another, if you want to know more about joining:
https://blog.codinghorror.com/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins/

I haven't tested this code so you might need to debug it when the copy paste fails.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but if I do that, I get 2 results, one with the first username, one with the other.
I want to get one result with both names like:
2017-03-17 15:00:00 - 2017-03-17 16:00:00 - Rainer - Horst

Answer (score 0):

This simple query should do the trick:

```
SELECT bookings.starttime, bookings.endtime, users.username FROM
bookings
INNER JOIN users
ON bookings.user1 = users.id OR bookings.usert = users.id
```

I tested the query, works well.

Answer (score 0):

you need to join same table two time

```
SELECT b.*,u1.*, u2.*
FROM bookings b
LEFT JOIN users u1
ON b.user1 = u1.id
join users u2 b.user2 = u2.id
```

try this But need both user present in table